# How to count only the number elements in a list (PROLOG), except _?

Tags: list, prolog

This code give me the number of zeros that is in a list. But if my list is `[0,_,0,0,_]`the code says that there is 5 zeros..

I wrote something like:

```
count([], 0).
count([H|T], N) :-
   count(T, X),
   (  H = 0
   -> N is X+1
   ;  N is X
   ).
```

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write H = 0, H is unified with 0, this succeeds if H is 0 or H is not unified with anything.
So you just have to test if H is **equivalent** to 0, use **==** instead of **=**.